# Clip Path is always overflow:hidden

Tags: css, clip-path

I made this example:

```css
div {
 -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 85% 100%, 0% 100%);
 clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 85% 100%, 0% 100%);
 background-color: red;
 width: 150px;
 height: 150px;
 position: relative;
}
ul{
 position: absolute;
 background-color: green;
 left: 30px;
 top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div>
 <ul>
   <li>1</li>
   <li>2</li>
   <li>3</li>
   <li>4</li>
   <li>5</li>
   <li>6</li>
   <li>7</li>
   <li>8</li>
   <li>9</li>
   <li>10</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

As you can see, there is a list with 10 numbers but due to clip path property, div behaviour is always as `overflow: hidden`.

How can I make all the `<ul>` visible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An idea would be to reproduce the same shape using background and avoid the effect of `clip-path`:

```css
div {
  background:
     linear-gradient(to top left,transparent 49%,red 50%) right/15% 100%,
     linear-gradient(red,red) left/85% 100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
}
ul{
  position: absolute;
  background-color: green;
  left: 30px;
  top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>10</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

If you want an image you can try this

```css
div {
  background:
    linear-gradient(to bottom right,transparent 50%,#fff 51%) right/15% 100%,
    url(https://picsum.photos/2000/1000?image=1069) center/cover;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
}
ul{
  position: absolute;
  background-color: green;
  left: 30px;
  top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>10</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

You can also update the `clip-path` to use bigger value than `100%`

```css
div {
  background:url(https://picsum.photos/2000/1000?image=1069) center/cover no-repeat;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 85% 100%,85% 1000%,0% 1000%,0% 100%);
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
}
ul{
  position: absolute;
  background-color: green;
  left: 30px;
  top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>10</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: nice..... how can I change the red color with an image? Is this compatible with ie11?

Comment: @Michalis updated with an image ;) and yes it's compatible .. it's more supported than clip-path as it rely on background

Answer (score 11):

You can do it with the `:before` or `:after` *pseudo-element*:

```css
div {position: relative}
div * {margin: 0; box-sizing: border-box}

div:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 85% 100%, 0% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 85% 100%, 0% 100%);
  background-color: red;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}

ul {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: green;
  left: 30px;
  top: 50px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>10</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```